# How does System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser (IFramed window) can communicate to its parent view in xaml(WPF)

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

How to do similar thing as below in WPF, the WebBrowser used in the below link belongs to windows forms. I have a requirement to communicate between parent(window opener) and child view's (window opened)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implement-two-way-com-between-dhtml-and-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved it using below http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/840/working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You can use WindowsFormsHost control https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/ to use WebBrowser and its properties and events in WPF and implement the same things as in your link